# How to use html helper classes with Razor Multi-Line syntax?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, razor

I use MVC3, in c# I have this multi-line razor code

```
@{
    var accessibilityVb = ViewBag.Accessibility;

    if (accessibilityVb == "accessibility")
    {
        Html.ActionLink("Accessibility On", "SetAccessibilityOn");
    }
    else if (accessibilityVb == "no-accessibility")
    {
    Html.ActionLink("Accessibility Off", "SetAccessibilityOff");
    }
}
```

The `Html.ActionLink` does not create the HTML code as expected.

What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try change

```
Html.ActionLink("Accessibility On", "SetAccessibilityOn");
```

To

```
@Html.ActionLink("Accessibility On", "SetAccessibilityOn")
```